# A PHP include path explanation

Tags: php

So I'm not exactly new to PHP but this has me really stumped.

My understanding of the PHP include paths is, when you set the paths, whether it be by ini, htaccess or set_include_path, so long as what is included is in one of those paths PHP should be able to find it. Example...

Directory structure.

- folderA

  - fileA.php
- folderB

  - fileB.php

Assuming I set the include path to be ... /folderA; /folderB

Then write an include in fileA like so

### ----- fileA -----

```
<$php 
     include 'fileB.php';
```

PHP should be able to find fileB. Is this correct?

Let me rephrase. If a file is in the include path, a relative path should be unnecessary ?

Comment: Is `/folderA` the actual absolute path from the **system root** to that folder? In other words, is the path literally "`/folderA`", or something like `/var/www/myapp/folderA`?

Comment: Either way. Does it matter if the folder was in the root directory or buried in some other folder? I do under stand the difference when running under a server situation where you may or may not be able to access items outside the web root.

Comment: Did you actually try your code? I ask because the way you ask your question could let us think that you didn't (sorry if I'm wrong about it). If you did, did it find it or not?

Comment: Its not just about access, / means "starting from the root", so if you say "/file" it will look into the root for a "file" file, not in the current folder. For that you use ./file

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It helped me clear up some ideas about how the include path works. As I see it now any path that is included acts as if it was in the top directory of php.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could either:

1. Specify the path from the root folder (starting with `/` up to `fileB.php`):

   Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` if you don't know which folder is the actual root)
2. Specify the path from the current directory (such as `../folderB/fileB.php`)

You might also want to check what the doc says [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) or [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) about how include paths actually work.

Comment: Thats all well and good. But then what is the point of having the 'include path" in the first place?

Comment: @kazambient Right. But I generally avoid using them for various reasons. Anyway, you could also always check the two links I added to my answer. Hopefully they'll answer your questions more the way you hoped for.